# NullPointerException while trying to test a Spring MVC controller method with JUnit, Mockito

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I am trying to unit test a Spring MVC controller method, but my unit test keeps failing.

I have a Spring MVC controller method:

```
// MyController.java
@RequestMapping(value = "/end-point", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    DataManager dataManager = DataManager.getInstance();
    DataUser currentUser = (DataUser) request.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser");
    List<DataItem> dataList = dataManager.getDataForUser(currentUser.getId());
    mv.addObject("dataList", dataList);
    mv.setViewName("home-page");
    return mv;
}
```

I am trying to test this controller method with JUnit. I have very little experience unit testing and am trying to learn. Seems like this is near-impossible or does not make sense to do without a mocking library, and the project I'm working on already has Mockito as a dependency so I'm trying to use that. My test class is below:

```
//MyControllerTest.java
public class MyControllerTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    @Mock
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Mock
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @Mock
    ModelAndView mockModelAndView;

    @Mock
    DataManager mockDataManager;

    @Mock
    DataUser mockDataUser;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getDataTest() throws Exception {
        //I guess I have to somehow mock mockDataUser here even more than @Mock???
        Mockito.when(request.getSession().getAttribute("currentUser")).thenReturn(mockVendorUser); // <-- this is where the null pointer exception is coming from
        Mockito.when(myController.getData(request, response)).thenReturn(mockModelAndView); 
        ModelAndView testing = profileControllerWH.getMySkus(request, response);
        assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

When I run my test, it fails and I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception in the console, specifying the line above with the null pointer exception comment.

I have tried looking up how to mock classes with Mockito, and I keep seeing the `@Mock` annotation, which I already have as `@Mock DataUser` (as well as other classes I am using in the controller method that I guess I need to mock).

How do I get this to work? It seems like I have to create a whole new `DataUser` object with fake data, but then that seems to defeat the purpose of the mocking library. What would the point of using Mockito be if I have to create my own objects with fake data? Or, I might be misunderstanding this because of lack of experience.

Comment: For your Spring MVC controller endpoints, it might make more sense to write a test using `MockMvc` as otherwise you end up mocking everything and duplicate your implementation. The following [guide about MockMvc](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/) might be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that by default, unstubbed methods return default value of return type when called (0 for numbers, null for Objects).

You haven't stubbed `request.getSession()` so it returns null.

You need to:

- provide a mock for session
- stub `request.getSession()` to return this mock
- stub `session.getAttribute("currentUser")`

On top of that:

While calling the controller method in your test certainly has value of testing the method body, but you will test more functionality (like request and response serialization) if you re-implement your test as a [@WebMvcTest](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#unit-testing-with-webmvctest)